# How to remove bootstrap tool bar in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am working on an angular 7 application. I took a build using "ng build --base-href=/angular/" command. I just gathered all files from dist folder and kept it in my dynamic web project in websphere.

when I try to execute my application which is developed by angular is working fine and the attached toolbar also displayed on top-right of the page.

PFA..

[image]

please help me to remove the toolbar

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please check via inspecting the element by hitting `ctrl+shift+i` and `ctrl+shift+c` and select the whole toolbar and check with the code and delete the whole `div` element.

Hope this helps!